Create container without horizontal scrollbar
I am trying to achieve below:
The container + the padding would actually be 1280px in total width.

Here is the snippet: container-flex

Here is the HTML code:
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="left-section">
    <nav aria-label="Page content navigation">
      <p>Menu item 1</p>
      <p>Menu item 2</p>
      <p>Menu item 3</p>
      <p>Menu item 4</p>
      <p>Menu item 5</p>
      <p>Menu item 6</p>
      <p>Menu item 7</p>
      <p>Menu item 8</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="right-section">
    <div>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness..."
    </div>
    <div>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born..."
    </div>
    <div>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born..."
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
       body {
            background: lightgrey;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0; /* Reset default margin */
            padding: 0; /* Reset default padding */
        }
        
        .outer-container {
            width: 1280px; /* Total container width including padding */
            padding: 20px; /* Add padding around the container */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding in the width calculation */
            margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */
            display: flex; /* Flex layout to align sections */
            gap: 60px;
        }

        .left-section {
            background:grey;
            padding-left: 20px;
            width: 300px; /* Fixed width for the menu */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in the width calculation */
        }

        .right-section {
            flex: 1; /* Fills the remaining space for content */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in the width calculation */
        }

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .outer-container {
                flex-direction: column; /* Stack sections vertically on smaller screens */
            }

            .left-section {
                width: 100%; /* Full width for the menu */
                margin-bottom: 10px; /* Space between sections */
            }

            .right-section {
                width: 100%; /* Full width for content */
            }
        }

The issue is, when we change the viewport to 1280px or 1140px in chrome development tools, there is a horizontal scrollbar.

This is expected I believe since most browsers dedicate part of the viewport width to allow space for the scrollbar whether it's visible or not, around 15 or 16px I think.

hmm, so is there any other solution?

Should I change it to something else?

Just change width: 1280px to max-width: 1280px
